# How did 索性 get translated as "you might as well (do it)"

Tags: etymology, phrase-meaning

I'm curious as to how 索性 came to be translated as "you might as well (do it)"

1. 索性: 直截了当,干脆
2. 索性：任性

索 apparently has English meanings of: large rope, cable; rules, laws; to demand, to exact; to search, inquire; isolated

:) You could translate 索性 as 'rope nature' :)

Which meaning of 索 is involved in 索性？

"might as well" is a subjunctive statement.

Is "might as well" an over-translation?
Where does 索性 come from?
Is 索性 actually a short version of something longer?

Comment: 索 could also mean 寂寞(loneliness) and 没有兴趣(no interest).  E. g. 索然无味.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a highly unsatisfying answer.

《汉语大辞典》has a definition of 索 that defines it as:

> 索性；干脆。

And they give the example:

> 《警世通言·庄子休鼓盆成大道》
> 早知死後無情義, 索把生前恩愛勾。

《现代汉语大词典》also has an entry on 索 that defines it as:

> 干脆。如：索性；索兴。

*Outlier* gives the following meaning tree which maps out the development of word meanings and it seems to show that this meaning was originally of a different tone:

> **MEANINGS**
> Character meanings
> suǒ
>
> 1 (orig.) two hands holding a rope made of plant stalks and leaves
> 2 → rope
>
> 3 ⇒ to search, follow a line
>
> 4  to ask, demand
>
> suó
>
> 1 ⇒ strip, line
>
> 2  simply

It would seem that suó was later merged into suǒ.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose we can, in the right context, bend the meaning of 'simply' or 'just' to 'might just as well': 既然已经做了，～就把它做完。找了几个地方都没有找着，～不再找了。